# Windows From Custom Label FromPosition and ToPosition after Xaxis min and max Range setting

Tags: winforms

I am using Windows From to generate custom charts.

I have axis data from 0 to 10 with interval of 1.0

The AxisX is in default range from -1 to 11 as shown in attached image.

I want to place custom labels on Top of the chart (AxisX2), I am using FromPosition=0.5-Interval & FromPosition=0.5+Interval, this is placing the custom label aligned with bottom X axis labels.

But when i limit the X axis range to 0 to 10, then custom label is not aligned with bottom X axis labels.

What i notice is custom label position remain fixed, but after setting the range position of the Grid position of the bottom X axis changed, so the is no alignment with bottom X axis and top secondary X axis custom label. Is there any way to align top X2 axis Custom label with bottom X axis labels ?

I am attaching my code, i would highly appreciate your help here.

[Screenshot of custom label setting alignemnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIaID.png)

```
class MainForm(Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.InitializeComponent()
    
    def InitializeComponent(self):
        global series11
        chartArea11 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea()
        ChartType11 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType()
        legend11 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend()
        series11 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
        series12 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
        series13 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
        title1=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title()
        Marker=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle()

        self._chart1 = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart()
        self._chart1.BeginInit()
        self.SuspendLayout()
        
            ##### Form and Chart size
        Width = 800
        Height = 450
        Buffer = 50

        self._chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea11)
        
        series11.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        series11.Legend = "Legend1"
            
        self._chart1.Size = System.Drawing.Size(Width-Buffer , Height-Buffer )  # Chart Area Size
        self._chart1.TabIndex = 1
        self._chart1.Text = "chart1"


        lista=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        listb=[0,8.27458E-06,0.003971857,-0.009233615,-0.022420625,-0.035589211,0.096930249,0.163891257,-0.009233615,0.003971857,-0.035589211]
        Time_1=[23,23,20,30,40,50,-50,-100,30,20,50]     
        
        # Chart Type
        self._chart1.Series.Add(series11)
        series11.ChartType=ChartType11.Line
        self._chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(lista,listb)
    
        
        ### Secondary Axis as Lables

        chartArea11.AxisX2.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True
        chartArea11.AxisX2.Title = " Temperature [\xb0 C]"
        chartArea11.AxisX2.TitleFont = Font("Arial", 10)    
        chartArea11.AxisX2.MajorGrid.Enabled = False;
        chartArea11.AxisX2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False;   
        
        CL_0=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_1=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_2=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_3=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_4=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_5=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_6=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_7=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_8=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_9=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel()
        CL_10=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel() 
        CLs=[CL_0,CL_1,CL_2,CL_3,CL_4,CL_5,CL_6,CL_7,CL_8,CL_9,CL_10]


        offset=0.5  
        for i in range(0,self._chart1.Series[0].Points.Count):
            CLs[i].Text=str(Time_1[i])
            CLs[i].FromPosition=self._chart1.Series[0].Points[i].XValue - offset
            CLs[i].ToPosition=self._chart1.Series[0].Points[i].XValue+offset
            chartArea11.AxisX2.CustomLabels.Add(CLs[i])
                    
        chartArea11.AxisX.Minimum = 0
        chartArea11.AxisX.Maximum = max(lista)
        chartArea11.AxisX.Interval=1.0  
        chartArea11.AxisX2.IsLabelAutoFit=False 
        
        ############ End secondary axis #####################   

        
        ############## MainForm############

        self.ClientSize = System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height+100)   ### Windows Form Area Size 
        self.Controls.Add(self._chart1)
        
        self.Name = "MainForm"
        self.Text = "Santhosh M WB Custom Charts Demo"
            
        self._chart1.EndInit()
        self.ResumeLayout(False)
        

from System.Windows.Forms import Application
Application.EnableVisualStyles()
form =MainForm()
form.ShowDialog()
#Application.Run(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I need to set both primary and secondary X axes range and interval same to align the custom label on secondary X Axis same as primary x axis label.

```
chartArea11.AxisX.Minimum = 0
chartArea11.AxisX.Maximum = max(lista)
chartArea11.AxisX.Interval=1.0 
 
chartArea11.AxisX2.Minimum = 0
chartArea11.AxisX2.Maximum = max(lista)
chartArea11.AxisX2.Interval=1.0
```